# On $\sum \frac{\mu(n) e^{i n/m}}{n^s}$

Tags: number-theory, dirichlet-series

Is anything known about the analytic continuation of 
\[
\sum \frac{\mu(n) e^{i n/m}}{n^s},
\]
where $\mu(n)$ is the Mobius function, into any region containing $s = 0$?

If I could know any reference on this, I would be very happy.

Thanks.

Comment: What restrictions do you have on $m$?

Comment: Nothing. Just integers. I want to let $m$ large, but I am guessing that RH may affect even in this type of analysis.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a $\pi$ in the exponential function?

Comment: If it makes the analysis easier, we can put any constant inside the exponential.